# regarding installation of php in windows

Tags: php, mysql

Sir I have download and installed php from .After installing i put the files into my c folder and set the path. But when I check wheather php is installed or not using command prompt by writing php -v then it tells me that MSVCR110.dll file is missing.

please help me out from this problem.

Comment: I think there is something messed up with your php installation (or maybe even your windows). Try installing a complete XAMPP stack: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html - there is a simple installer that should install and configure everything automatically in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Visual C++ libraries: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Make sure you get the x86 version even if you use a 64-bits OS because PHP needs some 32-bit libraries.